# Arabic rendering on android ICS and Jellybean

Tags: android, textview, rendering, arabic

I am developing an application is android (ICS, Jellybean). The arabic is not rendered properly.

Have a look at the problem.

[image]

I am using a TextView. Here is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Text"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00000000"
    android:textSize="30dip" />
```

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Fonts/Al Qalam Quran Majeed.ttf");

view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

I am also using arabic font. I have tried many fonts but problem wont go away.

Is text view right way of doing this ?

Comment: use font file for arabic

Comment: Yes i am using arabic font. Just updated the code above.

Comment: May be problem in withAl Qalam Quran Majeed.ttf ,try  tahoma.ttf or other ttf for check

Comment: Yes checked with many fonts. With tahoma its gets worse.

Comment: Could this be a mobile device issue. I am using a HUAWEI device. Kinda basic?

Comment: May be , last time try with this majalla.ttf same i used in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grppl.android.shell.CMBUMDroid

Comment: Ok will try on majalla.ttf and get back to you on this.